# Как сделать закругленные углы в html

Tags: html, html5, css

Как сделать закругленные углы в html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения этой проблемы можно воспользоваться css стилями.

Chrome, Safari.

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
```

Firefox.

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
```

Современный вариант для всех браузеров: `border-radius: 5px;`

Comment: был еще вариант с 5-6 тегами, он работает в IE и Opera

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky верно говорит

Answer (score 4):

Если у всех четырёх углов нужен одинаковый радиус, то можно написать одно свойство вместо четырёх:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
```

Последняя строчка для Оперы и ИЕ9.

Answer (score 1):

В свое время искал универсальное решение данной проблемы для всех браузеров, многие предлагали разместить в углах картинки с изображениями закруглений необходимого радиуса.

Comment: Для того, чтобы поддержать IE6+ без этого увы не обойтись

Answer (score 1):

Всего существует 3 варианта.

1-й: (от Expert)

```
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
```

2-й: (от Евген)

```
Спрайт с четырьями углами, положение задается через background-position
```

3-й: (самый старый способ)

```
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="b3"></div>
<div class="b4"></div>
```

Где классы имеют последовательное уменьшение отступов слевой и справой стороны.

Answer (score 0):

сокращенный вариант **border-radius: 10px 5px 4px 8px;**  углы начинаются от верхнего-левого/верхний-правый/нижний-правый/нижний-левый